# Custom Teams App - Collapse activity feed on click of notification

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

Not sure if this is something that can be done with a custom teams app, but when I send a notification to a user and they click it and it opens our app it keeps the activity feed open which then reduces the screen size of the app.

Just looking to see if there is a way you can make the activity feed collapse in once you click on the notification.

I have been looking at the MS docs but haven't seen anything like this so just wanting to know if it is even possible.

Comment: Just to confirm, if you are looking to close the activity feed after user clicks on bot notification as shown in screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/83sbW.png, it is currently not supported.

Comment: Yes that is it, I didn't think it was possible but wanted confirmation on it